Sign in with Windows Hello after password change
On my Windows 11 work laptop, managed by my company, my account does not have administration rights, but I have the possibility to login in the UAC elevation prompt as an administrator to enable many tasks (software installation, some specific settings, etc...), which is something I have to do frequently each day.
I have setup the fingerprint login, so I just have to sweep the reader when Windows is asking me to login in the elevation prompt, which is working quite well... until the IT changes the administrator password (almost every day). Using the fingerprint will then be rejected, with an error message explaining that I have to login with the password to reset Windows Hello.
At this point, I have to note down the (long) password carefully somewhere (or take a picture, or print it), close all my work, reboot the PC, directly login as the administrator with the new password, logout, login as normal user, execute some task requiring elevation and try the fingerprint reader. Sometimes it will work, sometimes I have to redo the full cycle 2 or 3 times until it works. This is just crazy.
So the question here is: how to reset Windows Hello so it just accept my fingerprint again, without having to enter the admin password either at the UAC elevation prompt (so each time I need elevation) or at the login screen (to make the fingerprint work again). Note that in both case, the clipboard is unavailable so I cannot even copy the new password from it.
One trick that I could find to login as an admin is to use the runas command in a shell, so I can execute anything as an admin and I can use the clipboard to copy the password. But unfortunately, it will not count as a new login for Windows Hello. But maybe it can allow me to run some specific commands to reset Windows Hello ?

We cannot answer this question because the policies applied to your computer by your employer govern how this works, and their frequent password rotation may be an attempt to prevent the very thing you are doing. You should bring your questions and concerns to your org's dedicated IT staff. If they allow fingerprint login, they may be able to adjust their policies to prevent what you're experiencing. If they do not allow, you will know not to continue doing this.

If you can authenticate as a user with Administrator rights through the UAC then you have access to an Administrator user.
